# How to solve reads package org.jdbi.v3.core from both ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guicey.jdbi3 and org.jdbi.v3.core

Tags: java, maven, modularity

Wanted to modularize the whole application, i.e. to migrate from Java 8 to Java 11, but with the modularity some dependency conflicts appeared.

[image]

[image]

These both jars are having the same name packages so that causes 100 + compilation errors with:

`[ERROR] error: module java.xml.bind reads package org.jdbi.v3.core from both org.jdbi.v3.core and ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guicey.jdbi3` messages.
Tried to exclude from ru.vyarus.dropwizard.guicey.jdbi3  org.jdbi.v3 using Maven but it did not work

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>ru.vyarus.guicey</groupId>
        <artifactId>guicey-jdbi3</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, deep dive into Java 9 gives the most basic answer, it's all about

> split packages issue

that should be solved.

Very interesting solutions are proposed in the section [How to Fix the Split Package Issue](https://www.romexsoft.com/blog/migrate-to-java-9/).